# Trying to push into the mercurial repo but unable to push

Tags: java, mercurial

Pushing into mercurial repo after changes results in the following:

```
searching for changes
1 changesets found
remote: adding changesets
remote: adding manifests
remote: adding file changes
remote: added 1 changesets with 92 changes to 92 files
remote: error: pretxnchangegroup.access hook failed: mercurialserver.access: access denied for changeset 5c225c5395f1
remote: transaction abort!
remote: rollback completed
remote: abort: mercurialserver.access: access denied for changeset 5c225c5395f1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mercurialserver.access: access denied
```

It looks like your server is running **[mercurial-server](http://www.lshift.net/work/open-source/mercurial-server/)**, an extension that manages users and rights and.. that you have the right to clone/pull this repo but not to push.

You should contact your server admin and ask him to give you the necessary rights.